# Test UI while idling resource is busy

Tags: android, rx-java, android-espresso, android-testing, ui-testing

I am new at android testing and I'm running into a problem. I am using RxJava and to test the UI I am using an IdlingResource. While idling resource is busy i cannot test UI.

For example: I have a button. onClick I'm doing a request. While requesting the button disables. After request the button is in enabled state. I want to test the following 3 steps:

1. Button is enabled before request
2. Button is disabled while requesting (onCLick)
3. Button is enabled when requesting ends and response message returns

I would be very very happy if you can help me in this issue...

If you need more information about my issue let me know it. I will edit my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understood, you're trying to test your UI. If so, please, make sure, that you do it in right way:

## **1).** You don't do **REAL** request.

Please, understand, that your test must always have ***same behaviour*** in similar situations. In other words, it must give ***same result***, you're passing same input parameters.
Your input parameters for now:
  1.1). Button is enabled before request
  1.2). Button disabled during the request
  1.3). Buttons enabled after request

As you can see from this list, you don't need to do a real request. It doesn't matter for you, what server will return you (error or success). You even don't need a server for this. All what you need, is just "something", that behaves like a real server. In other words, you have to mock your API client.

I suppose that you're using retrofit. If no, you have to create the `interface` wrapper for your client. If you're using retrofit, you just need to mock your `interface`.

Let's suppose, you have next `interface`:

```
public interface ApiClient{
    @GET("/items")
    Observable<MyResponse> doSomeRequest();
}
```

How do you usually create your API client:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
    .build();

ApiClient service = retrofit.create(ApiClient.class);
```

How you should do it in tests:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
```

and in test method:

```
ApiClient apiMock = mock(ApiClient.class);
when(apiMock.doSomeRequest())
                .thenReturn(Observable.just(fakeResponse));
```

or

```
ApiClient apiMock = mock(ApiClient.class);
when(apiMock.doSomeRequest())
                .thenReturn(Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<MyResponse>>() {
                        @Override
                        public Observable<MyResponse> call() {
                            try{
                                Thread.sleep(2 * 1000) //2 seconds
                            }catch(Exception e){
                                return Observable.error(e);
                            }
                            return Observable.just(fakeResponse);
                        }
                    }));
```

**P.S.** Retrofit adds `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` to all `Observable`'s by default. This mocked object doesn't do it. So, please, don't forget to add `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` in your code, or apply it to the result of `Observable.defer(...)`
In code above it will look like:

```
when(apiMock.doSomeRequest())
     .thenReturn(Observable.defer(...).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()));
```

And you should pass `apiMock` to `Activity` / `Fragment` which you try to test.
How to do it? **See #2**.

## **2).** Use DI (dependency injection)

I will not write a lot about it.
I just recomend you to read the documentation on http://google.github.io/dagger/

And especially, how to organise project in way, when you can use real implementaions for production, and mock implementations for testing:

http://google.github.io/dagger/testing.html

In other words, when you're going to build app for usage, you provide real dependencies(in your case it will be real implementation of `ApiClient`), and when you're going to test some UI or business logic, you pass mock dependencies, which have behaviour specified before the test by you.

*This is all, what I wanted to tell you. Hope this helped, and let me know if you have any other questions.*

Answer (score 1):

Small addition to [Alexander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40056834/2711056). I would use a `Subject` for "mocked" api. This allows you to control execution.

```
//setup your test 
Subject<Response,Response> stubResponse = AsyncSubject.create();
ApiClient apiMock = mock(ApiClient.class);
when(apiMock.doSomeRequest()).thenReturn(stubResponse.asObservable());
//check first condition that button is enabled before executing action
//click on button
//test your second condition that button is disabled while waiting for response
stubResponse.onNext(fakeResponse); //return fake response
stubResponse.onCompleted();
//test your third condition that button is enabled when you get response back
```

Remark. Never use `sleep` in your test. It will slow down your tests and add flakiness.